# How to ignore left part and middle element of the array(if odd array) to check existence of element in the right part?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to return

- **true**, if an item is within the second half of an array
- **false**, if the item is within the first half
- **false**, if it is the middle item of the odd array.

I have some working code to test this, however I am stuck at on making sure that the middle item of an odd array is not tested.

```js
function isItemPastHalf(array, item) {

  var halfWayThough = Math.floor(array.length / 2)

  var arrayFirstHalf = array.slice(0, halfWayThough);

  var arraySecondHalf = array.slice(halfWayThough, array.length);

  return arraySecondHalf.includes(item);

}

var array = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(isItemPastHalf(array, 2));
```

So far this code will not work on array = [1, 2, 3] item = 2 as 2 is the middle of an odd which should return false. The other tests for this particular problem include even length arrays. Has anyone got any suggestions for what I can use?

Comment: Why not use indexOf and compare with array length? No need to actually split the array.

Comment: Slicing the array is unnecessary and you can use the Array indexOf method to determine if the elements exists in the second half. You can refer to the following link for details about index of operation https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-array-indexof/

Comment: Thanks so much, I've managed to cut my code down so much using indexOf & Math.ceil and it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Math.ceil()` will do the trick here instead of `Math.floor()`

```js
function isItemPastHalf(array, item) {

  var halfWayThough = Math.ceil(array.length / 2);

  var arrayFirstHalf = array.slice(0, halfWayThough);

  var arraySecondHalf = array.slice(halfWayThough, array.length);

  return arraySecondHalf.includes(item);

}

var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

console.log(isItemPastHalf(array, 3));
console.log(isItemPastHalf(array, 2));
console.log(isItemPastHalf(array, 4));
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you. I've combined Math.ceil and using indexOf which means I'm able to complete this problem in two lines of code now!

Comment: @slouisa Glad to help you ;-). If this answer helped you, you can mark it as answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function isItemPastHalf(array, item) {
  let itemIndex = array.lastIndexOf(item)
  let mid = Math.floor(array.length/2)
  return mid <  itemIndex;
}

var oddLengthArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
var evenLengthArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

console.log("ODD LENGTH ARRAY")
console.log("3",isItemPastHalf(oddLengthArray, 3));
console.log("4",isItemPastHalf(oddLengthArray, 4));
console.log("5",isItemPastHalf(oddLengthArray, 5));

console.log("ODD LENGTH ARRAY")
console.log("3",isItemPastHalf(evenLengthArray, 3));
console.log("4",isItemPastHalf(evenLengthArray, 4));
console.log("5",isItemPastHalf(evenLengthArray, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

you might enhance the function by searching for the index first and then decide what to return as follows

```
function isItemPastHalf (array, item) { 
    let idx = array.lastIndexOf(item);
    let middleIndex = Math.ceil(array.length/2)-1;
    return idx > middleIndex; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method of Array.

```js
function isElementInTheSecondHalfOfTheArray(element, array) {
    const index = array.findIndex(arrayElement => arrayElement === element);
    return index > (array.length - 1) / 2; 
}

console.log( isElementInTheSecondHalfOfTheArray(1, [1, 2, 3]) );
console.log( isElementInTheSecondHalfOfTheArray(2, [1, 2, 3]) );
console.log( isElementInTheSecondHalfOfTheArray(3, [1, 2, 3]) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following approach:

```js
function isItemPastHalf(array, item) {
  // we find the index of the item in the array (which returns -1
  // if the item is not found) and check to see if that is greater
  // than, or equal to, the floored length of the array when divided
  // by 2; we use Math.floor() rather than Math.ceil() because
  // JavaScript arrays are zero-indexed:
  return array.indexOf(item) >= (Math.floor(array.length / 2));
}

var array = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(isItemPastHalf(array, 2));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cp6vLmsy/.

References:

- [`Array.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length).
- [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).
- [`Math.ceil()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil).
- [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor).

Answer (score 0):

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

function isItemPastHalf(array, item){
  if((array.indexOf(item)*2) > array.length)
    return true;
    return false
}

console.log(isItemPastHalf(numbers,3)) //false if it is the middle item
```

If the index of the item multiply by two is still smaller than the array length, the item must be on the first half.